# UICollectionViewController F#

Tags: c#, ios, f#, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement the following in F#:

```
    public class SimpleCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
{
    static NSString animalCellId = new NSString ("AnimalCell");

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(AnimalCell), animalCellId);

    }
```

however I don't know how to access the underlying `CollectionView` in the line:

```
 CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(AnimalCell), animalCellId);
```

This is my F# code:

```
[<Register ("LandlordHome")>]
type LandlordHome (handle:IntPtr) as x =
    inherit UICollectionViewController (handle)

    let NSString animalCellId = new NSString("AnimalCell")

    override x.ViewDidLoad () =
        base.ViewDidLoad ()

        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(AnimalCell), animalCellId)
```

however, this throws an error saying `The value, namespace, type or module 'CollectionView' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   Collections   CoreLocation   UICollectionView (FS0039)`